# DagBag does not populate dags as expected

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I want to test my dags to make sure they have certain default arguments and also to make sure that all dags are not having importation errors.

I am using DagBag to populate dags and then iterate through each dag and check for the values of each dag to make sure they are what I want them to be.

Because DagBag can fetch also the example dags that are shipped with airflow, I am passing the argument `include_example = False` however when I do this I realize that none of my dags is pulled into dagbags.

Am I using DagBag wrongly? or is there another better way to pull and inspect dags when testing?

My code

```
def test_no_import_errors():
    dag_bag = DagBag(include_examples=False)
    assert len(dag_bag.import_errors) == 0, "No Import Failures"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem, when creating the `DagBag` object, if you don't provide a value to `dag_folder` parameter, no DAG is added to the colleciton.

So as Jarek stated, this works:

```py
def test_no_import_errors():
    dag_bag = DagBag(dag_folder="dags/", include_examples=False)
    assert len(dag_bag.import_errors) == 0, "No Import Failures"
```

This is the example I made to test it:

```py
# python -m unittest test_dag_validation.py 
import unittest
import logging
from airflow.models import DagBag


class TestDAGValidation(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        log = logging.getLogger()
        handler = logging.FileHandler("dag_validation.log", mode="w")

        handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        log.addHandler(handler)
        cls.log = log

    def test_no_import_errors(self):
        dag_bag = DagBag(dag_folder="dags/", include_examples=False)
        self.log.info(f"How Many DAGs?: {dag_bag.size()}")
        self.log.info(f"Import errors: {len(dag_bag.import_errors)}")
        assert len(dag_bag.import_errors) == 0, "No Import Failures"
```

Answer (score 3):

When you construct DagBag objects you can pass folder list where DagBag should look for the dag files. I guess this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

By default airflow DagBag looks for dags inside AIRFLOW_HOME/dags folder.

This is usually stored inside airflow.cfg file.
By default it points to ~/airflow folder, but you can point to current working directory by running -

```
export $AIRFLOW_HOME=abs_path_of_your_folder
```

If you are using python for Airflow installation, make sure to export the $AIRFLOW_HOME variable first, then activate virtual environment and finally install airflow. This will make sure your path is properly attached to the airflow.cfg file.

Also you can check if your folder loaded properly or not, while running the unittest. In terminal, the file path is printed like

```
[2022-02-03 20:45:57,657] {dagbag.py:500} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/kehsihba19/Desktop/airflow-test/dags
```

An example file for checking import errors in DAGs which include checking typos and cyclic tasks check -

```
from airflow.models import DagBag
import unittest

class TestDags(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_DagBag(self):
        self.dag_bag = DagBag(include_examples=False)
        self.assertFalse(bool(self.dag_bag.import_errors))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```